# Ansible loops matching on array/dict_list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I have an array like so

```
our_domains:
  - domain: www.example.com
    urls:
      - { path: '/' }
      - { path: '/test1' }
  - domain: www.example2.com
    urls:
      - { path: '/' }
      - { path: '/test2' }
```

and in a template I want to match on a given domain and then loop over the contents of urls

e.g

```
    {% if item.value.domain == 'www.example2.com' %}
    {% for item_url in item.urls %}

   service_description    http://anotherwebsite.com{{ item_url['path'] }}

    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Im sure the FOR loop will work ok as its working in a similar context elsewhere in the code.

Im just struggling getting a conditional match on the domain name.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you want to execute the `template` task for each of the elements of the `our_domains` list.

you should just remove the `value` from the `if` statement, rest looks fine:

```
{% if item.domain == 'www.example2.com' %}
{% for item_url in item.urls %}

service_description    http://anotherwebsite.com{{ item_url['path'] }}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

if on the other hand, your intention was to generate only 1 file, you should use this template (one more for loop added enclosing the previous code):

```
{% for item in our_domains %}
{% if item.domain == 'www.example2.com' %}
{% for item_url in item.urls %}

service_description    http://anotherwebsite.com{{ item_url['path'] }}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```